# Why getting cxPacket when Maxdop=1?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I set `MAXDOP=1` on my server (standard, 2012 sp3), with an intention to shut down parallelism.  I'm wondering why am I still getting `CXPacket` waits?

The timing is during maintenance plan runs - so I suspect that those things (DBCC, index rebuilds maybe??) can run in parallel regardless of `maxdop`, but can't find anything that collaborates that.  There are no query hints to up the number in maintenance  plans or stored procs...  Any ideas out there?

P.S.: Why shutdown parallism?  It's a Microsoft recommendation for Dynamics GP, and I did some production monitoring with it set at both 2 and 1. There is better performance at 1.

Comment: I am not sure plans will be flushed ,when this setting is changed,can you try `DBCC FREEPROCCACHE WITH NO_INFOMSGS;`

Comment: please be aware that this flushes entire plans

Comment: also restricting parallelism is not a good idea,there are some cases when parallel plans can help

Comment: A potential hacky workaround is to bump `cost threshold for parallelism` to its highest value (32767). This should make the query optimizer basically not consider generating parallel plans even if a query should explicitly override it with `MAXDOP`. But, like @TheGameiswar, I doubt disabling parallelism for maintenance queries is a good idea, even if you do it for user queries.

Comment: Thanks - I've rebooted the server after that - still experiencing the issue.  My assumption was that rebooting clears the plan cache.  (that's not why I rebooted - something else required that)  Reading between the lines in some other posts - that's not necessarily true.  Correct?

Comment: @BillCummings: nope. The plan cache is purely in memory. Restarting SQL Server clears it. You can query its contents (and see which queries are producing the parallel plans) through [sys.dm_exec_cached_plans](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms187404).

Comment: Thanks - so, the question still is:  Do maintenance activities ignore maxdop?